# Overwriting a variable at the beginning of a JavaScript calculation with a produced variable

Tags: javascript

New to this and have an issue. I need to run a calculation - that will then compare a produced variable with a default value provided at the start and if different override the default and rerun the calculation. It’s all ifs and else right now....

An example would be

```
let defaultCount = 3;
defaultCount = actualCount ? actualCount : defaultCount;
actualCount = a + b.
```

So the problem is that in the beginning `actualCount` isn’t defined yet. So I need to ignore this, then rerun once it has been defined?

`defaultCount` is needed to get the comparison.
Thanks in advance!

so the at the top of the code I had

```
let appliedTaxRate = 0.45
if(incomeTaxRate == undefined) {
    appliedTaxRate = appliedTaxRate
} else {
   appliedTaxRate = incomeTaxRate
}
```

In between there are a lot of calculations that then add to the final comparison below, these need to use the default value for the first load up,
then it would need to rerun if the new calculated value is different than the
starting default value. Which makes the whole calculation need to run twice.

and at the base I have

```
//incomeTaxRate
if(totalEarnings>personalHigherUL) {
    incomeTaxRate = personalAdvancedRate
} else {
    if(totalEarnings>personalBaseUL) {
        incomeTaxRate = personalHigherRate
    } else {
        if(totalEarnings>personalZeroUL) {
            incomeTaxRate = personalBaseRate
        } else {
            incomeTaxRate = 0
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not init `actualCount` to `defaultCount` once only, and later simply update the value as needed?

Comment: @Yoshi I could write defaultCount = actualCount  but my thoughts were about using the if statement to refresh the calculation if it had update. I have a list of if statements that run and they rely on the actual value as well as effecting it. so I need to calculate a new actualCount and rerun it - unless I complete the first run and do a comparison off the outputs and run it again?

Comment: I assumed it wasn't that easy, but given your code I can't follow what's the actual problem is. I guess you'll need to extend your question to include code that makes it more obvious.

Comment: @Yoshi I have added more lines

Comment: I'm sorry, but seeing this, I'm not sure I can help. My feeling is that you drastically over-complicate things or it might simply be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). But given what you showed, I'd suggest creating a few *pure* functions that return values based on their inputs (e.g. `getIncomeTax(...)`, `getAppliedTax(...)`, ...). And by this way breaking the overall problem down to a few individually verifiable pieces of code. It will make reasoning a lot easier and the original problem might even simply *go away* by cleaning up.

Comment: Yoshi you are correct - the simplest way i have made it work is to wrap the calculations into one large function and run the function twice, after walking away from it for a while I just expanded the answer @barhatsor gave. Thank you for your feedback and patience!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to declare `actualCount` as undefined, then have a function check if it's defined. If not, `defaultCount` is used.

```js
let defaultCount = 3;
let actualCount = undefined;

checkCount();

actualCount = 1;
checkCount();

function checkCount() {
  if (actualCount) {
    defaultCount = actualCount;
  }
  console.log(defaultCount);
}
```

Comment: Sorry if this is a silly question.. but to then pull the defaultCount out of the function I would just use the return command rather than console.log?

Comment: That's right :) I only logged it to show how it works. You would do `return defaultCount;`

Comment: If this helped you, could you please choose my answer above ^

Comment: working on it still, but once i get there I will thanks

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: I ended up running the entire code twice just wrapping it in a function and then inputting the new Count in between the first and second solution. after considering your solution so thanks

Answer (score 0):

My general finished work around was like this:

```
let actualCount; 
let function = mainCalculation() {
    let function = primaryCalculation() {
         ...calculations
        };
    primaryCalculation();
    primaryCalculation();
};
mainCalculation();
```

I removed the if/else statements and the default variable.

Thanks for all the help